# Gift aid calculator task

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, tdd

I have recently taken a small technical test in C# and the following were expected:

- All stories to be completed with an appropriate level of testing.
- No actual database implementation is required, feel free to stub it out.
- Your code should trend towards being SOLID.
- Make sure you write mock objects and do good unit testing with this.
- Make sure that your tests actually pass
- Do not over engineer the test and make sure there is no repetition of code.

Please find my code in GitHub [Gift Aid Calculator](https://github.com/Shivan4u/GiftAidCalculator).  The story for the test can be found in the *read me* section of GitHub.

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using GiftAidCalculator.TestConsole.BusinessObject;
using GiftAidCalculator.TestConsole.Helper;
using GiftAidCalculator.TestConsole.Interface;
using GiftAidCalculator.TestConsole.Repositry;

namespace GiftAidCalculator.TestConsole
{
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        IConfigRepositry config = new ConfigRepositry();

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the tax rate:");

        decimal taxRate;
        if (ValidateHelper.ValidateDecimal(Console.ReadLine(), out taxRate))
        {
            config.TaxRate = taxRate;
            Console.WriteLine("**************   Promotion     ******************");
            Console.WriteLine("*****    5% Supplement added on running     *****");
            Console.WriteLine("*****    3% Supplement added on swimming    *****");
            Console.WriteLine("**************   Promotion     ******************\n");
            Console.WriteLine("\n Input 1 for Running, 2 for Swimming and 3 for other events.");

            int eventInput;
            if (ValidateHelper.ValidateInteger(Console.ReadLine(), out eventInput))
            {

                Console.WriteLine("\n Please Enter donation amount:");

                decimal donationAmount;
                if (ValidateHelper.ValidateDecimal(Console.ReadLine(), out donationAmount))
                {
                    var calculateTax = new TaxCalculator(config);


                    decimal giftAid = MathHelper.RoundDecimal(calculateTax.CalculateGiftAid(donationAmount));
                    Console.WriteLine("\n Gift aid calculated at the rate of "+ taxRate+" is:" + giftAid + "\n");

                    Console.WriteLine(EventRepositry.GetEventTypeMessage(eventInput)+ "\n");

                    Console.WriteLine("\n The calculated gift amount is: " + (donationAmount +giftAid + MathHelper.RoundDecimal(EventRepositry.GetEventSupplementAmount(eventInput, donationAmount))) + "\n");


                    Console.WriteLine("\n Press any key to exit.");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }

}}
```

**Interfaces**

```
 namespace GiftAidCalculator.TestConsole.Interface
{
  public interface IConfigRepositry
 {
   decimal TaxRate { get; set; }

}
}

namespace GiftAidCalculator.TestConsole.Interface
{
public interface ITaxCalculator
{
    decimal CalculateGiftAid(decimal donationAmount);
}
}
```

**Repositry**

```
using GiftAidCalculator.TestConsole.Interface;

namespace GiftAidCalculator.TestConsole.Repositry
{
  public class ConfigRepositry : IConfigRepositry
 {
    public decimal TaxRate { get; set; }
 }
}


using GiftAidCalculator.TestConsole.Entities;

namespace GiftAidCalculator.TestConsole.Repositry
{
public class EventRepositry
{

   /// <summary>
   /// Gets the event type supplement message.
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="eventCode"></param>
   /// <returns></returns>
   public static string GetEventTypeMessage(int eventCode)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;

        //validation for invalid event code.
        if (eventCode > 3 || eventCode <1){ eventCode = 3;}

        switch (eventCode)
        {
            case (int)GenericEntities.EventType.Running:
                result = "\n 5% supplement added for donations to running events.";
                break;
            case (int)GenericEntities.EventType.Swimming:
                result = "\n 3% supplement added for donations to swimming events.";
                break;
            case (int)GenericEntities.EventType.Others:
                result = "\n No supplement should be applied for other events.";
                break; 
        }

        return result;
    }


   /// <summary>
   /// Calculate event supplement amount.
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="eventCode"></param>
   /// <param name="donationAmount"></param>
   /// <returns></returns>
   public static decimal GetEventSupplementAmount(int eventCode, decimal donationAmount)
   {
       decimal result = 0;
       decimal eventSupplement = 0;

       //validation for invalid event code.
       if (eventCode > 2 || eventCode < 0) { eventCode = 2; }


       switch (eventCode)
       {
           case (int)GenericEntities.EventType.Running:
               eventSupplement = 5;
               break;
           case (int)GenericEntities.EventType.Swimming:
               eventSupplement = 3;
               break;
           case (int)GenericEntities.EventType.Others:
               eventSupplement = 0;
               break;
       }
       result = donationAmount*(eventSupplement/100);

       return result;
   }
}
}
```

**Business Object**

```
using GiftAidCalculator.TestConsole.Interface;


namespace GiftAidCalculator.TestConsole.BusinessObject
{
public class TaxCalculator: ITaxCalculator
{
    private readonly IConfigRepositry _configRepositry;

    public TaxCalculator(IConfigRepositry configRepositry)
    {
        _configRepositry = configRepositry;
    }


    public decimal CalculateGiftAid(decimal donationAmount)
    {
        var giftAidRatio = _configRepositry.TaxRate / (100 - _configRepositry.TaxRate);
        return donationAmount * giftAidRatio;
    }


}
}
```

**Helper**

```
using System;

namespace GiftAidCalculator.TestConsole.Helper
{
public  static class MathHelper
{
    //This can also be set as configurable member.
    private const int DecimalPoints = 2;


    public static decimal RoundDecimal(decimal giftAidAmount)
    {
        return decimal.Round(giftAidAmount, DecimalPoints, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
    }
}
}


namespace GiftAidCalculator.TestConsole.Helper
{
public class ValidateHelper
{

    public static bool ValidateDecimal(string strInput, out decimal dOutput)
    {
        dOutput = 0;
        bool result = decimal.TryParse(strInput, out dOutput);
        return result;
    }

    public static bool ValidateInteger(string strInput, out int dOutput)
    {
        dOutput = 0;
        bool result = int.TryParse(strInput, out dOutput);
        return result;
    }
}
}
```

**Entities**

```
namespace GiftAidCalculator.TestConsole.Entities
{
class GenericEntities
{
    public enum EventType
    {
        Running =1,
        Swimming = 2,
        Others = 3
    }
}
}
```

**UnitTest - As_event_promoter**

```
using System;
using GiftAidCalculator.TestConsole.Repositry;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace GiftAidCalculator.Tests
{
[TestFixture]
class As_event_promoter
{
    [Test]
    public void Add_5_percent_supplement_for_running()
    {
        //Arrange
        //Input one for running
        const int inputEvent = 1;
        const string expected = "\n 5% supplement added for donations to running events.";

        //Act
        string actual = EventRepositry.GetEventTypeMessage(inputEvent);

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(actual,expected);
        Console.WriteLine(actual);
    }


    [Test]
    public void Add_3_percent_supplement_for_swimming()
    {
        //Arrange
        //Input one for swimming
        const int inputEvent = 2;
        const string expected = "\n 3% supplement added for donations to swimming events.";

        //Act
        string actual = EventRepositry.GetEventTypeMessage(inputEvent);

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(actual, expected);
        Console.WriteLine(actual);
    }


    [Test]
    public void No_supplement_for_others()
    {
        //Arrange
        //Input three for others
        const int inputEvent = 3;
        const string expected = "\n No supplement should be applied for other events.";

        //Act
        string actual = EventRepositry.GetEventTypeMessage(inputEvent);

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(actual, expected);
        Console.WriteLine(actual);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Show_event_supplement_amount_for_running()
    {
        //Arrange
        const int eventCode = 1; //running
        const decimal donationAmount = 45.56m;
        const decimal expected = 2.278m;

        //Act
        decimal actual = EventRepositry.GetEventSupplementAmount(eventCode, donationAmount);


        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(actual,expected);
        Console.WriteLine("Calulated supplement amount for running event with donation amount '" + donationAmount + "' will be : " + actual);
    }

}
}
```

**UnitTest - As_site_administrator**

```
using System;
using GiftAidCalculator.TestConsole.Interface;
using GiftAidCalculator.TestConsole.Repositry;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace GiftAidCalculator.Tests
{
 [TestFixture]
class As_site_administrator
{
    [Test]
    public void Get_me_current_tax_rate()
    {
        //Arrange
        const decimal setCurrentTaxRate = 15.5m;
        const decimal expectedCurrentTaxRate = 15.5m;

        IConfigRepositry configRepositry = new ConfigRepositry();

        //Act
        configRepositry.TaxRate = setCurrentTaxRate;
        decimal actualCurrentTaxRate = configRepositry.TaxRate;

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(actualCurrentTaxRate,expectedCurrentTaxRate);
        Console.WriteLine("Current Tax Rate ["+ actualCurrentTaxRate + " %] is set and retrieved from data store.");
    }
}
}
```

**UnitTest - As_site_administrator**

```
using System;
using GiftAidCalculator.TestConsole.Interface;
using GiftAidCalculator.TestConsole.Repositry;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace GiftAidCalculator.Tests
{
[TestFixture]
class As_site_administrator
{
    [Test]
    public void Get_me_current_tax_rate()
    {
        //Arrange
        const decimal setCurrentTaxRate = 15.5m;
        const decimal expectedCurrentTaxRate = 15.5m;

        IConfigRepositry configRepositry = new ConfigRepositry();

        //Act
        configRepositry.TaxRate = setCurrentTaxRate;
        decimal actualCurrentTaxRate = configRepositry.TaxRate;

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(actualCurrentTaxRate,expectedCurrentTaxRate);
        Console.WriteLine("Current Tax Rate ["+ actualCurrentTaxRate + " %] is set and retrieved from data store.");
    }
}
}
```

**UnitTest - Gift_aid_should**

```
using System;
using GiftAidCalculator.TestConsole.BusinessObject;
using GiftAidCalculator.TestConsole.Helper;
using GiftAidCalculator.TestConsole.Interface;
using Moq;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace GiftAidCalculator.Tests
{
[TestFixture]
class Gift_aid_should
{

    private decimal CalculateGiftAid()
    {
        const decimal currectTaxrate = 15.65m;
        const decimal donationAmount = 50.50m;

        var mockConfigRepositry = new Mock<IConfigRepositry>();
        mockConfigRepositry.Setup(x => x.TaxRate).Returns(currectTaxrate);
        ITaxCalculator taxCalculator = new TaxCalculator(mockConfigRepositry.Object);

        return taxCalculator.CalculateGiftAid(donationAmount);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Be_rounded_to_two_decimal_digits()
    {
        //Arrange
        const decimal expectedValue = 9.37m;
        var calculatedGiftAid = CalculateGiftAid();

        //Act
        decimal actualValue = MathHelper.RoundDecimal(calculatedGiftAid);

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(actualValue,expectedValue);
        Console.WriteLine("Actual calculated gift aid was [ " + calculatedGiftAid + " ] which is rounded to 2 decimal points : " + actualValue);


    }
}
}
```

**UnitTest - Validate**

```
using GiftAidCalculator.TestConsole.Helper;
using NUnit.Framework;
namespace GiftAidCalculator.Tests
{
[TestFixture]
class Validate
{
    [Test]
    public void Invalid_decimal_input()
    {
        //Arrange
        const decimal expected = 0;
        decimal actual = 0; 

        //Act
        ValidateHelper.ValidateDecimal("invalid", out actual);

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(actual,expected);
    }


    [Test]
    public void Valid_decimal_input()
    {
        //Arrange
        const decimal expected = 24.536m;
        decimal actual = 0;

        //Act
        ValidateHelper.ValidateDecimal("24.536", out actual);

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(actual, expected);
    }


    [Test]
    public void Invalid_integer_input()
    {
        //Arrange
        const int expected = 0;
        int actual = 0;

        //Act
        ValidateHelper.ValidateInteger("invalid", out actual);

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(actual, expected);
    }


    [Test]
    public void Valid_integer_input()
    {
        //Arrange
        const int expected = 145;
        int actual = 0;

        //Act
        ValidateHelper.ValidateInteger("145", out actual);

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(actual, expected);
    }
}
}
```

**UnitTest - When_calculating_gift_aid**

```
using System;
using GiftAidCalculator.TestConsole.BusinessObject;
using GiftAidCalculator.TestConsole.Interface;
using Moq;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace GiftAidCalculator.Tests
{
[TestFixture]
class When_calculating_gift_aid
{

    [Test]
    public void Gift_aid_should_be_calculated_by_current_tax_rate()
    {
        //Arrange
        const decimal currectTaxrate = 20;
        const decimal donationAmount = 50;
        const decimal expectedResult = 12.5m;

        var mockConfigRepositry = new Mock<IConfigRepositry>();
        mockConfigRepositry.Setup(x => x.TaxRate).Returns(currectTaxrate);
        ITaxCalculator taxCalculator = new TaxCalculator(mockConfigRepositry.Object);

        //Act
        decimal actualResult = taxCalculator.CalculateGiftAid(donationAmount);

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult,actualResult);
        Console.WriteLine("Gift aid calculated at a tax rate of " + currectTaxrate + " is: " + actualResult);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: You should probably post the stories here, since, like the code, they seem to be critical to doing a review based on your requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**class Program.**

That's a class. A very high-level *abstract* notion of something with an *entry point* - a `Main` method. "Program" could be literally anything.

Writing [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) code implies [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), [OCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle), [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), [ISP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) and [DIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).

---

> ```
> public class ValidateHelper
> ```

Uh-oh. Red flag. `Helper` smells. Let's see...

> ```
> public static bool ValidateDecimal(string strInput, out decimal dOutput)
> ```
>
> ```
> public static bool ValidateInteger(string strInput, out int dOutput)
> ```

`strInput` and `dOutput` ring the *Hungarian Notation* bell. And there's a <kbd>Copy</kbd>+<kbd>Paste</kbd> error, I'm guessing `dOutput` in `ValidateInteger` was meant to be named `iOutput`... How about this?

```
public static bool ValidateDecimal(string value, out decimal result)
```

```
public static bool ValidateInteger(string value, out int result)
```

I'm only addressing the *naming* here though.

The main issue I'm seeing, is that the abstraction level at the entry point is very low, but in a SOLID app it's very high.

And the ending isn't very elegant either, and pretty much fails at [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself):

```
                Console.WriteLine("\n Press any key to exit.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Try writing your application top-down. Take the time to put your mindset at the *abstraction level* that's right for the code you're writing. With the wrong abstraction levels, it's hard to make *units* for *unit testing*.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        IDataService dataService = new SomeDataService();
        IUserInteractionService interactionService = new ConsoleInteractionService();

        var app = new CalculatorApp(dataService, interactionService);
        app.Execute();
    }
}
```

**SRP**

The `Main()` method does one thing: it *composes* the application, and runs it. The composition is done with *Poor Man's DI* instead of with an IoC container, but refactoring to use one would be very easy.

**OCP**

Being `static`, the `Main()` method **cannot be extended**. The more code we write here, the more *reasons to change* we introduce, the further we stray from being *open for extension, closed for modification*. Writing code at the proper abstraction level helps succeeding here.

**LSP**

Code against *abstractions*, code against the *interface* of objects - don't assume you know what the *actual* runtime type is going to be (see the "typical violation" section [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)). In other words, `SomeDataService` could very well be fetching its data from async calls to a web service that returns JSON or XML data - `Program` doesn't need to know that much (abstraction levels again).

**ISP**

*Interface Segregation* boils down to the fact that *modifying an interface is a breaking change*. Observe the [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) principle here: the *interface* of a `CalculatorApp` object only exposes a parameterless `Execute` method. It's unlikely that anything else is ever going to be needed, because all the entry point ever needs to be doing is *everything it takes* to run this `Execute` method.

**DIP**

*Dependency Inversion* means that instead of `new`ing up dependencies, a class will be *injected* with implementations for its dependencies, preferably through its constructor. Because CalculatorApp requires implementations for `IDataService` and `IUserInteractionService`, you already know that this class' responsibility will be to coordinate the interactions between these *services*, implementing the *business logic*.

In order to run the `Execute` method, `Main` has to instantiate a `CalculatorApp`. Because I'm injecting *abstractions*, I can write a unit test suite to cover everything the *business rules* dictate, where I'm free to inject a mock implementation for every dependency and verify that method X or Y is called N times on the `IDataService`, or whatever.

---

By building the app *top-down* by writing the *abstractions* first (actually with TDD, you'll first write a failing unit test) and peeling off abstraction levels as you dive into the low-level `Console.WriteLine` calls, you decide how much abstraction is enough abstraction, and it gets easier to realize how much abstraction is outright *over-engineered*: write only the code you need to write for tests to pass. Writing the app bottom-up in `Main` and refactoring towards SOLID makes this much harder than *expanding the idea* as you go from one level of abstraction to the next.

Comment: Mat that was very helpful. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like your switch code...

```cs
switch (eventCode)
{
    case (int)GenericEntities.EventType.Running:
        result = "\n 5% supplement added for donations to running events.";
        break;
    case (int)GenericEntities.EventType.Swimming:
        result = "\n 3% supplement added for donations to swimming events.";
        break;
    case (int)GenericEntities.EventType.Others:
        result = "\n No supplement should be applied for other events.";
        break; 
}
```

I think it's better idea to operate on objects.

```cs
using System;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var chosenEvent = Event.CreateEvent(1);

        Console.WriteLine(chosenEvent.GetEventTypeMessage());
        Console.WriteLine(chosenEvent.GetSupplementAmount(1000));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class Event
{
    private readonly string _name;
    private readonly decimal _suplement;

    public decimal GetSupplementAmount(decimal donationAmmount)
    {
        return _suplement * donationAmmount;
    }

    public string GetEventTypeMessage()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}% suplement added for donations to {1} events.", _suplement * 100, _name);
    }

    public static Event CreateEvent(int id)
    {
        if (id == 1)
            return new Event("running", 0.05m);
        else if (id == 2)
            return new Event("swimming", 0.03m);
        else if (id == 3)
            return new Event("other", 0.0m);
        else
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
    }

    private Event(string name, decimal suplement)
    {
        _name = name;
        _suplement = suplement;
    }
}
```